Custom group pattern layout is not showing in posts
I have created a group layout in one of my blog posts.
I can import that layout into any new blog post.
It shows perfectly in the editor option but doesn't show anything in the view page when I save the post.
In the view, the layout disappeared.
Can anyone help?


